# Is a non-clustered index implicitly created for each foreign key in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reference, sql-server-2014

If I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    FooId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Foo(Id),
    Data NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

The following observations may be made:

1. A clustered index will be created on the primary key column `Id` *on the table `MyTable`*.
2. Also, as can be inferred, a clustered index will be created *on the table `Foo`* for its primary key named `Id`.

**Question:**

Will there also be created an index for the foreign key `Foo.Id` *on the table MyTable*?

In other words, is a non-clustered index created implicitly for every foreign key *on the dependent table*.

In still other words, will the total number of indices created in this schema be 2 as follows:

1. A clustered index for the primary key `Id` on the table `MyTable`.
2. A clustered index on the primary key `Id` on the table `Foo`.

Or will there be the following 3 indices:

1. A clustered index for the primary key `Id` on the table `MyTable`.
2. A clustered index on the primary key `Id` on the table `Foo`.
3. A non-clustered index on the foreign key `Foo(Id)` on the table `MyTable`.

My question pertains to Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Not in SQL Server (or most databases).  Such an index is created in MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not created automatically. It is a good practice to create it manually:

[The Benefits of Indexing Foreign Keys](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys)

> Unlike primary key constraints, **when a foreign key constraint is defined for a table, an index is not created by default by SQL Server**.
>   However, it's not uncommon for developers and database administrators to add them manually

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
  Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
  FooId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Foo(Id),
  Data nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
);

exec sp_helpIndex 'MyTable'

index_name  index_description   index_keys
PK__MyTable__3214EC0742A69968   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY Id
```

Explicit index creation:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), 
  FooId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Foo(Id),
  Data nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
  INDEX FK_FooId nonclustered(FooId)  -- inline syntax
); 

exec sp_helpIndex 'MyTable'

index_name  index_description   index_keys
FK_FooId    nonclustered located on PRIMARY     FooId
PK__MyTable__3214EC0779B032FB   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY Id
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fdce39a99b3fcca45e00476beec26e0)**

Comment: This answer: perfection.  Clear, concise, correct. (And TIL capitalization doesn't matter on sprocs - Sp_HeLpInDeX, even!)